# Create default forms(NewForm.aspx, DispForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx) programmatically (have ~1000 lists without forms)

Tags: list, newform, default

Don't You know how to add default forms to standard lists (have many webs with same bug, they were created from broken template). If I add new forms in SPD all is Ok. But I have about 200 webs with 6 lists without forms on every web :)

Comment: you mean you need to add forms across site collections including subsites.

Comment: Yes, there is one site collection with ~200 webs(SPWeb). and there are missing forms in lists (lists without NewForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx, DispForm.aspx)